# document.height not affected by jquery calls.

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, height

I have already followed instructions on how to make a specific div height take up the entire document. I created the following function, which works perfectly when the page is first loaded.

```
function resizeBody() {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(window).resize(function() {
                $('.body').height((document).height - $(".topbar").height() - 30);
            });
            $(window).resize();
            console.log(document.height);
        });
    };
```

In another section of my code, I am hiding and showing divs using jquery to create tabs. These tabs are all of different heights. The code is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".tab").click(function () {
            $(".tab_content").hide();
            $(".tab").css("font-weight","normal");
            resizeBody();
        });
        $("#infoButton").click(function() {
            $("#info").show();
            $("#infoButton").css("font-weight", "bold");
        });
        $("#toolsButton").click(function () {
            $("#tools").show();
            $("#toolsButton").css("font-weight", "bold");
        });
        $("#dataButton").click(function () {
            $("#data").show();
            $("#dataButton").css("font-weight", "bold");
        });
        $("#visButton").click(function () {
            $("#vis").css('display','inline-block');
            $("#visButton").css("font-weight", "bold");
        });
        resizeBody();
    });
```

My problem is that when I hide or show a div, the properties of the document aren't updated.  Calling console.log(document.height) in the resizeBody() function still prints the original height of the document. Oddly, when I type "document.height" directly into the developer console, the correct (resized) value is printed.

Additionally, after opening the developer console, the page seems to update (without any kind of refresh) and the body div is correctly resized.

What am I missing here? Is this a problem specific to Chrome or am I misunderstanding something fundamental about the way javascript deals with the document object.

It may be important to note that all of my divs use inline-block as their display style. Each div gives a specific value for it's height in the web inspector.

Comment: It doesn't make a lot of sense to stash your code inside a `$(document).ready()` handler like that (inside the "resizeBody" function).  That code should simply be the code of "resizeBody" itself.

Comment: I had originally done that to make sure jquery had finished hiding/showing the other divs before it tried to do the resize. It doesn't change anything if I take it out though.

Comment: Oh, well you're calling "resizeBody()" just once. Don't you need to call it when each tab is shown?

Comment: You're right! I was calling resizeBody() right after hiding all of the tabs. After changing it to call after showing the proper div, it all worked.